# Запуск исполняемых файлов на windows-сервере

Tags: клиент, сервер, exe

Здравствуйте!
Я бы хотел уточнить, возможно ли запустить ***.exe файл**, расположенный на сервере, на клиентском компьютере. Вот, например, на локальном **windows-сервере** все сделать получилось.
Интересно, возможно ли это сделать с глобального? Большое спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

А в чем трудность? Достаточно выложить прямую ссылку на exe-файл на скачивание, после чего пользователь загрузит файл на свою машину и при желании запустит на исполнение.

Comment: Это если файл весит не более 1 МБ... А что делать, если на сервере,допустим, надо запустить целую игру ?  =)

Comment: В любом случае, если нужно запустить на машине клиента exe-файл, клиенту необходимо предварительно его получить (то есть загрузить).